# Delete a file from sharepoint folder by programatically

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

i want to delete a folder programatically.

the code below i wrote for this reason

```
 function deleteFile(fileUrlParam) {

     var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
     this.web = ctx.get_web();
     ctx.load(this.web, 'Include(Title, Id, Created, ServerRelativeUrl)');

    context.load(web);*/
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(onDeleteGetFileUrl(fileUrlParam), onDeleteFileFailure);
}


function onDeleteGetFileUrl(fileUrlParam) {



    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();//gets the current context
    var web = context.get_web(); //gets the web object


    var fileUrl = 'https://stackoverflow.com'  + fileUrlParam;
    var fileToDelete = this.web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(fileUrl);
    fileToDelete.deleteObject();
    context.executeQueryAsync(onDeleteFileSuccess, onDeleteFileFailure);
} 

function onDeleteFileSuccess() {
    alert("File got deleted");
}

function onDeleteFileFailure(sender, args) {
    alert('Failed to delete a file. Error:' + args.get_message());
}
```

but it gives an error. since the sharepoint language is turkish the error is also turkish and it says that

'Geçersiz istek'

i do not know exact match in english but it means 'invalid request' or smth like that

Comment: Are you trying to delete a file or a folder?

Comment: As method name suggests `this.web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(fileUrl);` should use path without host and protocol.

Comment: @Robbert i tried to delete both a file and a folder but in two cases i got same error.

Comment: @MarekKembrowski i removed the line over   var fileToDelete = this.web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(fileUrl); part but i also got same error

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you got the code from here:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0e18a8/delete-a-file-in-a-document-library-in-sharepoint-2013-using/

Did you make sure to follow all the steps correctly? 
Is the web from the context loading properly?
Are you using the correct WEB url?

Did you remove the comment from this line or is it a typo?

```
context.load(web);*/
```

Could you try doing the same thing using PowerShell/Server side code maybe it is another issue?
I think you need to provide some more details.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SP.Web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee659135%28v=office.14%29.aspx) to return the folder object located at the specified server-relative URL, then [SP.Folder.deleteObject() Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee658935%28v=office.14%29.aspx) to delete a Folder object.

### How to delete a Folder object via CSOM (JavaScript) in SharePoint 2010

```
function deleteFolder(folderUrl,success,error){  
   var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var web = context.get_web();
   var folder = web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderUrl);
   folder.deleteObject();

   context.executeQueryAsync(
   function() {
        success();
   },
   error
  );
}
```

Usage

```
deleteFolder('/project/Shared Documents/Orders/',
  function(){
       console.log('Folder has been deleted'); 
  },
  function(sender,args){
       console.log(args.get_message());
  }
);
```

Note: Since `SP.Web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl` method expects server relative Url, you could basically specify the folder Url in the the following formats:

- `/project/Shared Documents/Orders/` - `/<WebRelativeUrl></ListUrl>/<FolderUrl>`
- `Shared Documents/Orders/` - relative Url for a *current web* that
  consists of `<ListUrl>/<FolderUrl>`